# "it's all in the wrist"

Tags: expressions, catch-phrases

What is the meaning and origin of this idiom?

Internet searches are confounded by the many headlines and jokes that allude to the phrase superficially (e.g., “repetitive strain injury – it's all in the wrist”).

Comment: Google the phrase in quote marks for a start like I just did for a good basis for your question.  If you have any further questions, bring them here after you've done some preliminary research.

Comment: @kristina lopez In all fairness, I did google it (in Canada) out of curiosity but there's nothing about the origin of the expression or its meaning in the ten first result pages. Most of the hit were for the game Hitman.

Comment: @JoBedard, thanks for the reminder.  I should have mentioned that I Googled it in the US.  The OP should mention what research attempts were made to help the site members from repeating that work.

Comment: I agree totally

Comment: There's no idiom exactly here, just a lack of expressiveness. It is intended to mean 'do something different with your wrist'. Your phrase is just better than saying 'Wrist!' and pointing.

Comment: @Mitch No, there's definitely an idiom here, sometimes used metaphorically, sometimes facetiously: It's how an expert explains a particular nuance of skill.

Comment: @KristinaLopez There's definitely a lot of noise out there – references to carpal tunnel syndrome, business names, song lyrics, joysticks, piloting aircraft, most of them making a weak joke based on the idiom. I haven't had any luck tracking down an origin. It seems like the sort of thing that originated in a joke or in sports coaching (or both).

Comment: @BraddSzonye, I'd imagine it would be a tennis, golf or baseball reference, maybe even fishing.  There's definitely a tongue-in-cheek quality to it, implying, IMO, that something that looks difficult is easy if you master the nuance of the wrist action. Can't wait to find out the origin...I'm really curious now! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez This [list of movie quotes](http://www.subzin.com/s/It's+all+in+the+wrist) has examples dating back to the 1940s, including “Miracle on 34th Street” (1947), so it's been around for a while at least. No luck finding an origin yet.

Comment: There's a scene in the movie "Groundhog Day" in which Bill Murray is teaching Andie McDowell how to pitch playing cards into a hat.  The two are sitting on the bed together and Bill, who has experienced a year or two in a row of only Groundhog days, is quite an expert by now.  He instructs Andie, "It's all in the wrist."  "It's" is shorthand oversimplification  for "the technique that almost guarantees success."  If you'd practiced pitching cards as Bill Murray did for 700+ days in a row, you too would likely acquire the technique.  It's all in the wrist--and 700+ days of practice in a row!

Comment: I've even heard people use this expression about calligraphy, even though in most types of calligraphy, it's specifically *not* all in the wrist - you're supposed to use your whole arm, keeping your wrist mostly still.

Comment: Remeber that sentence in the older Bond movie "Octopussy" surrounding a backgammon (tafla) match between Bond and the evil Khan. Always understood it as "in a game wih cubes, everything is possible" because one throws cubes from his wrist.

Comment: The first time I heard this was in reference a close up street magician who performed a variety of tricks as well as pick pocket maneuvers. When asked how he did it, his response was. "Its all in the wrist."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The earliest reference I found was about [tennis in 1898](http://books.google.ca/books?id=oBegAAAAMAAJ&q=%22is%20all%20in%20the%20wrist%22&dq=%22is%20all%20in%20the%20wrist%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=6T6NUemfPMftygG3_IDgDQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA), but the importance of using the wrist to control a movement instead of placing all bets on the strength of the arm predates it [by at least a hundred years](http://books.google.ca/books?id=gdkvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22in%20the%20wrist%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=vjyNUe_KNOHsyQHE-4GADQ&ved=0CGcQ6AEwCDgU#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20wrist%22&f=false) in fencing.

Basically, although it might not be an "official" idiom you'd find in a reference book, I've seen it constantly used to mean – metaphorically or literally – that you can achieve your result using less strength but more control.

Comment: I've also seen it used metaphorically (and perhaps facetiously) as a way to declare mastery. For example: “Whoa, how'd you get that woman's phone number?” “It's all in the wrist!”

Answer (score 4):

It's cliche' sports advice that dads and coaches give when mentoring young athletes... "keep your eye on the ball" and "it's all in the wrist" are sort of the "tastes like chicken" of sports advice.

Want to hit that home run? Just remember, *'It's all in the wrist'*. Want to become better at tennis? Just remember, *'It's all in the wrist'*. Trying to toss that perfect pitch?
You know the deal -- **It's all in the wrist.**

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any clear reference you might never know for sure, but I'd say there's a good chance that it originated with fly fishing. The technique for properly casting the lure requires skillful wrist action.

Another possible origin I can think of is Bowling, but I'd give more weight to fly fishing because of its age.

Answer (score 1):

In the Hungarian language they say *csuklobol* which means *from the wrist*!
In English it is *in the wrist*, but both mean the same thing. It is a way of saying or declaring that someone is a master at something. They are so good at whatever that they make it look easy. They can whip or just shake it out right out of their wrists.

Everyone has something that they can master.

Comment: A handle all for this one post? Niiice :)